# Can I see how many EuroBonus points I will get for a SAS flight before taking it?

Tags: loyalty-programs, sas

I have an upcoming flight with SAS which should net me a decent amount of points if past history is anything to go by. I would like to know this given that I'm very close to the number of points necessary to book another flight I might do this summer, but I'm not sure if this will give me enough to bridge the gap, so I'm thinking that maybe I could do some minor upgrade just to get those last points necessary to pay for that flight using them if the deficit is small enough.

However, I can't find exactly how many points it will yield when browsing their website, which I have an account on and have booked the flight through. Is there any way I can see how many EuroBonus points an upcoming SAS flight booked through their website will give me?

Comment: No idea if they have a place where you can find out directly how many points you will get, but the details of how they are computed are [here](https://www.flysas.com/en/eurobonus/partners/airlines/scandinavian-airlines/). You’ll need details of the flight, ticket type/booking class, your membership level, any upgrades, biofuel options… it can range from 100 to over 18000 points… Some airlines show the info in the “manage my booking” section, do they not?

Comment: @jcaron My first instinct was to look there, but I couldn't really find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted the SAS support about this. They told me that you can see how many points you will get from a particular flight at the time of booking, but this only applies to flights operated by SAS. If it's operated by another carrier but booked through the SAS website, the only way of seeing how many points you will get is contacting the SAS support. Additionally, while you supposedly can see the number of points you will get at the time of booking (I didn't verify this myself), after booking it's not possible to see this until you've flown the flight.

In conclusion:

- If you're entirely taking flights operated by SAS, you can note down how many points you will get at the time of booking. If you didn't do that, you have to contact the SAS support to see how many points you will get.
- If your itinerary includes flights not operated by SAS, the only way to know how many points you will get is by contacting the SAS support.